# Firebase Cloud message works in simulator but not working on IOS device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement push notification using Firebase cloud messaging.I have followed firebase official tutorial from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client
It works in simulator and i get the message which i sent from firebase console but it does not get InstanceID token(FCM token) when i try to build it in a device.

Here is my AppDelegate code

```
debugging environment : IOS 10.3
//---------------PUSH NOTIFICATION IMPLEMENTED HERE------------------

- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication*)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
// Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
// show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
    // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
} else {
    // iOS 8 or later
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 
__IPHONE_10_0
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        }];

        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
#endif
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    // [END register_for_notifications]
}

//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
// [START configure_firebase]
[FIRApp configure];
// [END configure_firebase]
// [START add_token_refresh_observer]
// Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                             name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
// [END add_token_refresh_observer]
return YES;
}

// [START receive_message]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
// If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
// this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
// TODO: Handle data of notification

// Print message ID.
if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
}

// Print full message.
NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)
(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
// If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
// this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
// TODO: Handle data of notification

// Print message ID.
if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
}

// Print full message.
NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
// [END receive_message]



// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 
__IPHONE_10_0
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the 
foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
   willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
// Print message ID.
NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
}

// Print full message.
NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
}

// Print full message.
NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
    }

#endif
// [END ios_10_message_handling]


// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 
__IPHONE_10_0
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
// Print full message
NSLog(@"%@", [remoteMessage appData]);
}
#endif
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
// time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
// should be done.
NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

// Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
[self connectToFcm];

// TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START connect_to_fcm]
- (void)connectToFcm {
[[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
    }
}];
    }
// [END connect_to_fcm]


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can 
  be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so 
  that the APNs token can be paired to
// the InstanceID token.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
NSLog(@"APNs token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);

// With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
 [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
    }
```

How can I show notification.please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to change.I set a message from firebase console for later delivery and it works perfectly.firebase console time and my iphone time mismatch that's why it did not send the message immediately.